No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XXX
Trying to use Hibernate to persist data into a existing database called "vendas", all the tables are properly created beforehand, and as far I searched I don't need to do any different when using Hibernate to Persist in existing tables, even so my problem isn't this one YET
I've properly created EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager, but Hibernate is saying that "No Persistence providers for EntityManager"
I don't know why but I tried everything, I am on verge of going insane.

I am using maven, so my persistence.xml is in META-INF in resources folder.
Both my persistence.xml and EntityManagerFactory both dont have typos
I am using Hibernate 6

Stack Trace
out. 15, 2024 2:25:49 PM jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
ADVERTÊNCIA: jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu-vendas
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at com.example.SistemaDeVendas.SistemaDeVendasApplication.main(SistemaDeVendasApplication.java:26)

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SistemaDeVendas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SistemaDeVendas</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

main class
public class SistemaDeVendasApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Configuracoes do Swing
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainScreen");
        MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();
        frame.setContentPane(mainScreen.getMainScreen());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Configurações do Hibernate
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu-vendas");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // instanciação dos objetos para salvar no banco de dados
        Produto produtoBiscoito = new Produto(null, 20, "Biscoito Decorado", "Baunilha", 20.00F);
        Produto produtoPipoca = new Produto(null, 20, "Pipoca Gourmet", "Pão de Alho", 9.00F);
        Produto produtoBrownie = new Produto(null, 20, "Lascas de Brownies", "Chocolate", 15.00F);

        // Começa a transação com o banco de dados
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // Persiste os dados no banco de dados
        em.persist(produtoBiscoito);
        em.persist(produtoPipoca);
        em.persist(produtoBrownie);

        // Finaliza a transação com o banco de dados
        em.getTransaction().commit();

persistence.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">

    <persistence-unit name="pu-vendas">
        <class>com.example.SistemaDeVendas.entidades.Produto</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendas?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>

            <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


Remove <type>pom</type> from the hibernate dependency.

Can you show persistence.xml?

@AndreySmelik I forgot the persistence.xml sorry!
